# Printing ASCII characters in Golang

Tags: go, printf, ascii

I'm currently learning Golang and working on a code piece that where I'm printing all the Extended ASCII characters to console.
I've made my loop go from X80-XFF, and it works fine. However, I want to print a line in the bottom of the loop output that says "€ ÷ ¾ dollar", but my code only prints out the hex for the three characters I want to print + dollar. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
package ascii

import "fmt"

const Ascii = 
"\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f" 
+
"\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f" +
"\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf" +
"\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf" +
"\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf" +
"\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf" +
"\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef"+
"\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff"


func IterateOverASCIIStringLiteral(sample string) {
for i := 0; i < len(sample); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%X %q %b\n", sample[i], sample[i], sample[i])
}
}

func ExtendedASCIIText() {
    fmt.Printf("%q","\x80\xf7\xbe dollar")
}
```

Throwing in my main.go for good measure:

```
package main
import "./ascii"


func main() {
ascii.IterateOverASCIIStringLiteral(ascii.Ascii)
ascii.ExtendedASCIIText()
}
```

Comment: There's no official "extended ascii" character set. If you mean "ISO 8859-1", then you would have to encode it properly yourself. Go assumes strings are utf-8.

Comment: Could using []bytes be an alternative here?

Comment: An alternative to what, and how? Now seeing that you have a euro symbol here, but expect it to be 0x80, I'm not sure what encoding you're expecting. If your terminal is using the same encoding, then you could write the raw bytes to the terminal. Most terminals however also usually use utf-8 by default, so you would need to encode it properly.

Comment: What I want to do is to generate a print from a sequence of bytes ([] bytes).
I've tried looking at something like this:    
`func ExtendedASCIIText() string {
 message := []byte("\x80\xf7\xbe")
 for i := 0; i < len(message); i++ {
  fmt.Printf("%q", message[i])
 }
 output := string(message)
 return output
    }
`
But I don't know enough about the [] bytes type to be able to figure it out. Any tips?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the `[]byte` type (though you really should know how that works here, because it is fundamental to just about everything). You still haven't specified what character set you're expecting, but it looks like it might be `windows1252`? The [charmap package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap) has the tables to deal with that. But if you don't know what these things are, or how to do it, you would really just be better off sticking with utf8 like everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Yes. You don't appear to understand the problem. The term extended ASCII is not well-defined. You likely want to translate from (Windows) code page 1252 to Unicode.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func cp1252ToUTF8(cp string) string {
    r := make([]rune, len(cp))
    for i := 0; i < len(cp); i++ {
        r[i] = cp1252[cp[i]]
    }
    return string(r)
}

func main() {
    cp := "\x80\xf7\xbe dollar"
    str := cp1252ToUTF8(cp)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", str)
}

func init() {
    for i, r := range cp1252 {
        if r == 0 {
            cp1252[i] = rune(i)
        }
    }
}

// cp1252 to Unicode table
// ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT
var cp1252 = [256]rune{
    0x80: '\u20AC', // EURO SIGN
    0x81: '\uFFFD', // UNDEFINED
    0x82: '\u201A', // SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
    0x83: '\u0192', // LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK
    0x84: '\u201E', // DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
    0x85: '\u2026', // HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
    0x86: '\u2020', // DAGGER
    0x87: '\u2021', // DOUBLE DAGGER
    0x88: '\u02C6', // MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
    0x89: '\u2030', // PER MILLE SIGN
    0x8A: '\u0160', // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON
    0x8B: '\u2039', // SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x8C: '\u0152', // LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE
    0x8D: '\uFFFD', // UNDEFINED
    0x8E: '\u017D', // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON
    0x8F: '\uFFFD', // UNDEFINED
    0x90: '\uFFFD', // UNDEFINED
    0x91: '\u2018', // LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x92: '\u2019', // RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x93: '\u201C', // LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x94: '\u201D', // RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x95: '\u2022', // BULLET
    0x96: '\u2013', // EN DASH
    0x97: '\u2014', // EM DASH
    0x98: '\u02DC', // SMALL TILDE
    0x99: '\u2122', // TRADE MARK SIGN
    0x9A: '\u0161', // LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON
    0x9B: '\u203A', // SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
    0x9C: '\u0153', // LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE
    0x9D: '\uFFFD', // UNDEFINED
    0x9E: '\u017E', // LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON
    0x9F: '\u0178', // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/U3dlRahOxQN

Output:

```
"€÷¾ dollar"
```

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[The Unicode Consortium](https://unicode.org/)